# Remove Google Calendar custom property with java library

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am trying to remove some properties that I have stored in events. It works fine with direct API call:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
{
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "petsAllowed": null
    }
  }
}
```

Example is taken from here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/extended-properties#deleting

But, it does nothing when I use java library for it:

```
PATCH 
ExtendedProperties extendedProperties = new ExtendedProperties();
extendedProperties.getShared().putIfAbsent(key, null);
originalEvent.setExtendedProperties(extendedProperties);
```

After the patch, I still have old custom properties not deleted, even though I sent null values for their keys.

I suspect that it's general mechanism problem that stands behind processing PATCH requests by Google Java Library. It might cut all the null values.

Do you know the workaround for me to delete properties? I can't use UPDATE since I don't have enough data to fill out the object for this operation.

Comment: Patch will only update the values that you send.  Any values you leave out will not be updated.  Do a event.get on the event you are after.  When you get response back remove the one you dont want then use that to send the patch I can probably give you an example in C# if this doesnt make any sence the java and C# libraries are very close.  I am just not a java dev so wouldnt be the best to give you a java example

Comment: Used that idea. Thank you. You can make post an answer. Code is not necessary.

Comment: You may want to edit my answer and put in a bit of code if you have time.   It could help someone someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch only uodates the values you send.

Do a file.get and remove the record that you don't want not just the text.

then preform the patch useing this object.